# Acitve Directory: Handling attributes with LARGE_INTEGER / INTEGER8 syntax

Tags: vb.net, attributes, active-directory, ldap

I have an vb.net app that handles directory service attributes. I have to display the attribute values. To get the values I use LDAP.

Microsoft's Active Directory has the syntax (or type) LARGE_INTEGER / INTEGER8. I saw various LDAP-Browsers that display this type of attribute as DateTime. But [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684427.aspx) says that this syntax (or type) is a 64-bit signed integer value.

My question: Does the schema definition provide an information where I can detect that an attribute with the LARGE_INTEGER syntax should be handled as DateTime or not?

Here is an example:

- **lastLogoff** -> DateTime
- **msExchVersion** -> No DateTime

Both attributes have the same syntax.

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to the following post it seems that there is no way to see whether a LARGE_INTEGER attribute should be handled as DateTime or not :\

[Same datatype Storage but different representation in AD (UsnChanged and LastLogon)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e96b2976-e281-42d9-9bf3-1c79a3523580/same-datatype-storage-but-different-representation-in-ad-usnchanged-and-lastlogon?forum=winserverDS)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The LARGE_INTEGER thing is an abstraction at the ADSI layer. If you look at the docs for the lastLogoff attribute, for example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676822(v=vs.85).aspx), you'll see the actual AD syntax is Interval. You can grab the syntax for a given attribute off the attribute definition in the schema.