# Convert variant of type (Dispatch)

Tags: delphi, ado

I am trying to use Delphi 7 / ADO to read the lastLogonTimeStamp field in AD for each user. My loop can read the fields required. The string fields are easy to use, but I have failed to decode the timestamp. It is of type Variant and vartype returns 9 (Dispatch)

I've tried various typecasts, including INT64 (which I believe is how the timestamp is stored), and varToStr. All the records are vartype 9 except one which is vartype 1 probably because it is empty.

```
ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
ADOQuery1SN: TWideStringField;
ADOQuery1CN: TWideStringField;
ADOQuery1AdsPath: TWideStringField;
ADOQuery1lastLogonTimestamp: TVariantField;
logonfield : variant;

    logonfield := ADOQuery1lastLogonTimestamp.value;
    stringgrid1.Cells[1,i] :=  vartostr(logonfield);
```

I want to get date of last logon for each user, with exceptions filtered by the program. I can get the string fields OK. But I get:

Error: could not convert type (dispatch) into type (string) 
[or anything else I tried! TDateTime, INT64 ...]

Comment: What is the exact SQL you are using with your ADOQuery1?

Comment: `SELECT AdsPath, lastLogonTimestamp,CN, SN
FROM 'LDAP://OU=DomainUsers,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=COM'
WHERE objectClass='user' ORDER BY lastLogonTimestamp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant type 9 (`varDispatch`) represents a COM `IDispatch` object interface. Which makes sense in this situation because `lastLogonTimeStamp` is an `Integer8` in [`FILETIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) UTC format, wrapped in a COM object to expose access to its `LowPart` and `HighPart` members. See [Attributes for AD Users : lastLogonTimestamp](http://www.selfadsi.org/ads-attributes/user-lastLogonTimestamp.htm) and [Acitve Directory: Handling attributes with LARGE_INTEGER / INTEGER8 syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905407/) for more details.

Try something like this:

```pascal
function LargeIntegerToDate(value: Variant): TDateTime;
var
  ftUTC, ftLocal: TFileTime;
  st: TSystemTime;
begin
  Result := 0;

  if VarIsNull(value) then
    Exit;

  if not VarIsType(varDispatch) then
    raise Exception.Create('Unsupported type');

  ftUTC.dwHighDateTime := value.HighPart;
  ftUTC.dwLowDateTime := value.LowPart;

  if (ftUTC.dwLowDateTime = 0) and (ftUTC.dwHighDateTime = 0) then
  begin
    Result := EncodeDate(1601, 1, 1);
    Exit;
  end;

  try
    FileTimeToLocalFileTime(ftUTC, ftLocal);
    FileTimeToSystemTime(ftLocal, st);
    Result := SystemTimeToDateTime(st);
  except
  end;
end;

...

var
  logonfield : Variant;
begin
  logonfield := ADOQuery1lastLogonTimestamp.Value;
  StringGrid1.Cells[1, i] := DateToStr(LargeIntegerToDate(logonfield));
end;
```

Comment: I didn't get email notification of an answer, so in desperation I googled "lastlogontimestamp remy lebeau" coz he always knows. And I got redirected here! Thanks so much.